# Power of a prime ideal in a commutative ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am at a very initial stage of commutative algebra. I want to  know whether the power of a prime ideal in a commutative ring is prime ideal or not?

Comment: Notice that $(2)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$, and $(2)^2=(4)$. But $4$ is not a prime number and $(4)$ is not a prime prime ideal.

Comment: $4 \in 4\mathbb{Z}$, but $4=2 \cdot 2$ and $2 \notin 4\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

An ideal $I \subset R$ is prime iff $R/I$ is an integral domain (that is, it contains no nontrivial zero divisors).

If $I$ is a prime ideal such that $I^2 \neq I$, then in the quotient ring $R/I^2$ the elements of the form $x + I^2$, where $x \in I$, will be nilpotents. Thus, $R/I^2$ is not a domain and $I^2$ is not prime.

For a concrete and illustrative example, consider $I = (p) \subset \mathbb{Z}$ - the ideal of the ring of integers generated by a prime $p$. Then, $I^2 = (p^2)$, and is not prime (since it is generated by a non-prime integer).